# improper text alignment from pytesseract

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, python-tesseract, pypdf

Trying to extract data from pdf using pytesseract with below code. But text alignment is improper when printing/Writing data to doc.

```
from PIL import Image 
import pytesseract 
import sys 
from pdf2image import convert_from_path 
import os  
PDF_file = "d.pdf"
pages = convert_from_path(PDF_file, 500) 

image_counter = 1

for page in pages: 
    filename = "page_"+str(image_counter)+".jpg"
    page.save(filename, 'JPEG') 
    image_counter = image_counter + 1


files = os.listdir("JPEG_PATH") 
for i in files:
  text = str(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(i),lang='eng'))))
  print(text)
```

Sample.PDF

```
Category A       2015
A1              45,908
A2              67,876
A3              9,888
                ------
Total A count    123,672
```

Expected:

```
 Category A  2015\n
 A1 45,908\n
 A2 67,876\n
 A3 9,888\n
 Total A count 123,672\n
```

Actual Result is something like this

```
Category A\n
A1\n
A2\n
A3\n
Total A count\n
2015\n
45,908\n
67,876\n
9,888\n
```

Comment: Are you sure that's not a correct representation for the given pdf? A pdf can look a certain way, but it doesn't have to actually be encoded like that.

Comment: Yes i am Sure, Some of the other pages with same format is as expected. Only few pages are improperly aligned